# ¿Como obtengo el país de un archivo cvs mediante la longitud y altitud con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero detectar desde que país están visitando mi web y para eso uso la función de navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() para obtener la latitud y longitud; el tema es que después no se que hacer con eso!!
Como no quiero depender de google, me arme un .cvs con la siguiente información: https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv en el siguiente formato:

```
AD;42.546.245;1.601.554;Andorra
AE;23.424.076;53.847.818;United Arab Emirates
AF;3.393.911;67.709.953;Afghanistan
```

Y el problema ahora por supuesto es que no se como consultar el archivo .cvs para transformar la latitud y longitud que tengo en el nombre del país...

¿Alguien seria tan amable de darme una mano con esto?

Comment: Claro, primero en considerar usar la IP del visitante en lugar de latitud y longitud con javascript por 2 motivos: 1. Es más fácil. 2. No requiere que el usuario acepte ser "stallkeado" por la app.

Comment: Existen un montón de servicios para este tipo de cosas, por ejemplo: https://ipapi.co/api/